# 400 error when I send Document url toTelegram bot with api

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot, bad-request

I want to send MP3 file in telegram with my bot but some files return 400 error.
foe example this url 
http://www.dl.noisera.com/files/musics/1586023395/introhanditdown.mp3
 is not send and return 400 error but  this url
 http://www.dl.noisera.com/files/musics/1586023929/hardknocklifeghettoanthem.mp3 
is send.
my api code is:

```
 $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bot_id.'/sendDocument?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&document=http://www.dl.noisera.com/'.$_POST["musicFile"];

file_get_contents($url);
```

what is problem?

Comment: Are you constantly receiving this message for that file? or it is a transient error that just sometimes happens for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram servers have cache problems, it takes a few hours for new links to be found by their servers. You should manually download the file with your server and upload it when you get that error.